# Expired Post with More Recent Time Stamp?

Tags: posts, database, server

Im having issues with custom posts not showing in worpdress.

I see in my posts table theres two enters for each custom post

X - Has a date Jan14th- 2:06pm  - post_status: expired

Y - Has a date Jan14th- 2:05pm  - post_status: inherit.

Would that be my issue? That posts like X are seen as expired?

Comment: None of them are showing, or just Y?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that what you are looking at are post revisions. The posts with status "expired" are the primary post. The ones with "inherit" are revisions or autosave. Look at the `post_name` column and you should see a pattern like `**-autosave-**` or `**-autosave-**`, and then look at the `post_parent` column and your "expired" post ID should match. The primary post-- the parent post-- is apparently the one that matters to whatever software works out the "expired" status. So, yes, I think that is your issue. I don't know why or how your posts got the "expired" status.